# Docker - no route to host after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I've been using docker-compose for a few apps for years, and recently, after upgrading the host OS from Ubuntu 18.04 to to Ubuntu 20.04, when I run the test container, it's not able to connect to the DB container, giving the message:

`could not connect to server: No route to host`

I've tried:

- restarting the docker service (`sudo systemctl restart docker.service`)
- adjusting some weird network-related Kernel config that someone recommended.
- looking at `iptables` to see docker's entries... I can't tell if they're correct or not, but there are some there.

What could be causing this change, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm curious why 2 people have voted to close this?  Is there something I should know not to do in future posts?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, I just had to re-create the docker networks and containers:

**WARNING**: If you have any data in your containers that you don't want to lose, don't do this!

```sh
$ docker-compose down # removes all containers and networks associated with the compose config
$ docker-compose up # re-creates them
```

There's also the option of removing just the network: `docker rm network [network-name]`, but this seems to leave the containers in an unusable state, trying to connect to the old network, even after the new one is created... there's probably a way to fix this, if you have data you don't want to lose.  (I just haven't looked into it)